# Generating random values with Scala

Tags: scala, random

I am using this method to generate a random token in Scala:

```
  def randomString(alphabet: String)(n: Int): String =
    Stream.continually(Random.nextInt(alphabet.size)).map(alphabet).take(n).mkString
```

I use this method to generate a default value for a form:

```
  val userForm = Form(
    mapping(
      "token" -> default(text, (randomString("0123456789abcdef")(40))),
      "username" -> optional(text),
      "email" -> email,
      "password" -> nonEmptyText,
      "gender" -> nonEmptyText
    )(User.apply)(User.unapply)
  )
```

Why do I always get the same token when running this code?

Comment: If you execute `randomString` as written, it generates random tokens. Have you tried it in isolation?

Comment: Are you reusing the `userForm`? Is so then that's your problem. `default` takes `(Mapping[A],A)` not `(Mapping[A],=>A)`, so you only generate one token and then use it every time. I've put this as an answer, but this might not be your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `randomString` works as expected. The problem is with how you're using it.

The [`default[A](mapping: Mapping[A], value: A)`](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.data.Forms%24) method is getting a value from `randomString(...)(...)` and that value stays with the `Form` that you've just created. So `userForm` will use the same *random* token every time it has use the default.

Were you to create a new `Form` every time then you would not have this problem. This would be as easy as changing `val` to `def`. But there is certainly a better way to do it.

---

The alternative would be to create your own [`Mapping`](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.data.Mapping) that acts `default` but takes a thunk as its second argument.

Comment: Thanks @ggovan. userForm is defined in my Application controller. This code runs in Play framework. It is being called in one of my Actions: "userForm.bindFromRequest.fold("...

Comment: And you are correct: the code for generating the random value is called only once. The question is: how do I assign a random value to a form field.

Comment: As I've added to my answer, make your own mapping. You could probably just copy most of it from the source of the `default` method in `Forms`.

Answer (score 0):

`scala.util.Random` is using `java.util.Random` for generating random numbers.
`ju.Random` is using 48 bit seed for generating random numbers.
If you create two instances of `Random` with same seed (as in your case) they'll return same sequence of random numbers.

You should create `Random` class with non default constructor that takes seed number.
For ex. you can use `currentTimeMillis` for seed.

Comment: But no seed is being used here. This is using the companion object, which uses the zero-args constructor of scala Random and java Random. And the zero-args constructor of java Random says _sets the seed of the random number generator to a value very likely to be distinct from any other invocation of this constructor._